No. of one-one functions satisfying the given condition
So this question particularly deals with permutations and combinations and it goes like:

Let A = {1,2,3,4,5} and B = {0,1,2,3,4,5} then the number of one-one function f : A → B that can be defined so that f(i) ≠ i  ∀ i = 2,3,4,5 and f(1) ≠ 0 or 1 is -

My try:
The answer to this problem was given as D₆.(4/5) + D₅. I tried using derangement to solve this problem. I added an element, suppose 0, to set A and the did the derangement of 6 things. But we get those cases in which 1 is mapped with 0 and the mappings of 0 to some element of B. How do I remove these cases? Better explanations are appreciated.

The term $D_5$ counts the number of functions $f: A \to B$ in which $f(i) \neq i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$ and $0$ does not appear in the range.  Therefore, the author is claiming that $\frac{4}{5}D_6$ is the number of functions $f: A \to B$ in which $0$ is in the range, $f(i) \neq i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$ and $f(1) \neq 0$.

Good thought. The real question is how could one justify the term D₆.(4/5). How does one conclude that it is denotes the number of such functions as you said?

Personally, I prefer Inclusion-Exclusion here.  See this article for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see this answer for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion formula.
Let $~S~$ denote the set of all 1-1 permutations, ignoring the constraints on $~f(1), \cdots, f(5).~$
For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,5\},~$ let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where the constraint on $~f(k)~$ is violated.
Then, the desired computation is
$$| ~S ~| - | ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_5 ~|. \tag1 $$
Let $~T_0~$ denote $~| ~S ~|.~$
For $~r \in \{1,2,\cdots,5\},~$ 
let $~T_r~$ denote
$~\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 5} | ~S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r} ~|.$
That is, $~T_r~$ denotes the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{r}~$ terms.
Then, by Inclusion-Exclusion theory, the computation in (1) above is equivalent to
$$\sum_{r=0}^5 (-1)^r T_r.$$
Therefore, the problem reduces to computing
$~T_r ~: r \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,5\}.$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_0}$
There are $~6~$ choices for $~f(1),~$ then $~5~$ choices for $~f(2),~$ and so forth.
So,
$$T_0 = 6!.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_1}$
To compute $~| ~S_1~|,~$ consider that there are $~2~$ choices for $~f(1),~$ and then $~5!~$ choices for the remaining domain elements.
To compute $~| ~S_k ~| ~: k > 1,~$ consider that there is $~1~$ choice for $~f(k),~$ and then $~5!~$ choices for the remaining domain elements.
Therefore,
$$T_1 = (2 + 4) \times 5! = 6!.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_r ~: ~r \geq 2}$
Clearly, $~T_5 = 2,~$ since $~f(1)~$ has $~2~$ choices.  The remainder of this section assumes that $~2 \leq r \leq 4.$
I will use the variables:

$T_{ra}~$ to denote that one of the subsets in violation is $~S_1.~$

$T_{rb}~$ to denote that $~S_1~$ is not one of the subsets that is forced to be in violation.


$T_{ra}~$ may be represented by
$$| ~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \cdots \cap S_r ~|. $$
There will be $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{r-1}~$ such terms, and each term will equal
$$2 \times (6-r)!.$$
Therefore,
$$T_{ra} = \binom{4}{r-1} \times 2 \times (6-r)!.$$
$T_{rb}~$ may be represented by
$$| ~S_2 \cap S_2 \cap S_{r+1} ~|. \tag1 $$
There will be $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{r}~$ such terms, and each term will equal
$$(6-r)!.$$
Therefore,
$$T_{rb} = \binom{4}{r} \times (6-r)!.$$
So,
$$T_r = T_{ra} + T_{rb}$$
$$= (6-r)! \times \left\{ ~\binom{4}{r} + \left[ ~2 \times \binom{4}{r-1} ~\right] ~\right\}.$$

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
The computation is
$$\sum_{r=0}^5 (-1)^r T_r$$
where

$\displaystyle T_0 = 6!$

$\displaystyle T_1 = 6!$

$\displaystyle T_5 = 2.$

For $~2 \leq r \leq 4,$ 
$\displaystyle T_r = (6-r)! \times \left\{ ~\binom{4}{r} + \left[ ~2 \times \binom{4}{r-1} ~\right] ~\right\}.$


